# Rails Server won't complete

Tags: ruby-on-rails, server

I'm relatively new the coding world so apologies upfront if this is vague or i'm mis using some jargon...

I am trying to create a new application using Ruby on Rails. Having created the app, I went to run it on my local machine by typing rails server  but it seems as though the server won't complete..any thoughts? I only get as far as the below and then nothing else materialises to indicate the server has successfully completed... I've tried shutting down the server and trying again but no luck

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.3 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2017-04-29 15:58:45] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2017-04-29 15:58:45] INFO  ruby 2.3.1 (2016-04-26) [x86_64-darwin16]
[2017-04-29 15:58:45] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1493 port=3000
```

Comment: Try removing the pid on `tmp/pids/server.pid` and/or stopping spring `spring stop`, also you could try launch it binding a new port `rails s -p 4000`.

Comment: Hi, could you tell me how to implement what youve suggested above? Sorry- I'm fairly new to coding generally!

Comment: Well, yes, as I can't see more log than what you provided, just type first `spring stop` and then run again your `rails s` but this time adding `-p 4000` to point to the port 4000 instead the custom that's 3000, check it.

Comment: Did it work?, tell me to try to elaborate a better answer.